# Plotly Dash: save and display selected rows using custom pagination

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash application. I am using dash's data table, in that I have used `pagination` which is `custom` . Below is the callback. What I am trying to do is,

1. I am displaying a dataframe which has single column and some rows. From this user can select some rows from different pages and clicks on save button, after this I am trying to get the selected rows using `derived_virtual_selected_row_ids` and creating a new column as `used` which contain `True` if selected, `False` otherwise. I am saving this updated dataframe into `pickle` file.
2. On revisiting the page, I am trying to display the selected rows on different pages.

Dash table

```
table: dash_table.DataTable = dash_table.DataTable(
        id="table",
        # data=df.to_dict("records"),
        columns=[{"name": column, "id": column} for column in df.columns],
        row_selectable="multi",
        selected_rows=[],
        style_as_list_view=True,
        style_table={"height": "300px", "overflowY": "auto"},
        style_cell={"textAlign": "left"},
        style_cell_conditional=[
            {
                "if": {"column_id": "A"},
                "textAlign": "left",
            }
        ],
        page_action="custom",
        page_current=0,
        page_size=2,
    )
```

```
@callback(
    # Outputs
    Output(component_id="table", component_property="data"),
    Output(component_id="table", component_property="selected_row_ids"),
    # Inputs
    Input(component_id="table", component_property="page_current"),
    Input(component_id="table", component_property="page_size"),
    # States
    State(component_id="table", component_property="derived_virtual_selected_row_ids"),
    # prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def load_pages(page_current: int, page_size: int, derived_virtual_selected_row_ids: Any):


    row_ids: list = list()
    selected_row_ids: list = list()

    df: pd.DataFrame = get_updated_dataframe() 
    # This returns pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'used': [True, False, False, True]}) reads from pickle file

    if df.empty:
        df = get_dataframe()  
        # This returns original df as pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
    else:
        row_ids = df["used"].to_list()
        # if df is saved after selecting rows
        

    selected_row_ids = row_ids if row_ids else derived_virtual_selected_row_ids

    data: Any = df.iloc[(page_current * page_size) : ((page_current + 1) * page_size)].to_dict("records")

    return data, selected_row_ids
```

The data table is rendred properly, I am able to view different pages.

Issue: On selecting few rows on one page and then switching to another page and selecting few rows there. Now revisiting the earlier page, All checked rows are lost(deselected). Selected check marks does not retain on any page.

```
@callback(
    # Outputs
    Output(component_id="msg", component_property="children"),
    # Inputs
    Input(component_id="save", component_property="n_clicks"),
    # States
    State(component_id="table", component_property="derived_virtual_selected_row_ids"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def save_info(click: int, derived_virtual_selected_row_ids: Any):


    df: pd.DataFrame = get_dataframe() 
    # This returns original df as pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
    
    df.assign(used=True if df['id'].isin(derived_virtual_selected_row_ids) else False) # how to save the selected row ids
    
    msg = 'Rows are saved'
    
    return msg
```

Issue: how to save the selected row ids by creating a new column `used`

In both callbacks, `derived_virtual_selected_row_ids` is empty.

Can someone shed a light on how to save and display the selected rows using `custom pagination`. I tried searching examples for the same but no luck.